# Runtime error: signed integer overflow: -2147483648 * -1 cannot be represented in type 'int'

Tags: c++, integer-overflow

The below program is to check whether a number (say "n") prime factors are limited to 2,3,and 5 only or not. But program gives me signed integer overflow runtime error. Can anyone please help me in solving this problem? Here's the piece of code:

```
 bool check(int n)
   {
       if(n<0)
       n=n*(-1); // If 'n' is negative, making it positive.
       int count=1; //'count' variable to check whether the number is divisible by 2 or 3 or 5.
       while(n!=1 && count)
       {
           count=0;
           if(n%2==0)
           {
               n/=2; count++;
           }
           else if(n%3==0)
           {
               n/=3; count++;
           }
           else if(n%5==0)
           {
               n/=5; count++;
           }
       }
       if(n==1)
       return true;
       else return false;
       
    }
```

Program gave me this error:

**runtime error: signed integer overflow: -2147483648 * -1 cannot be represented in type 'int'**

Comment: Then maybe you want a 64 bit int like: `int64_t` instead of a 32 bit `int`

Comment: 32 bit integer can represent from -2,147,483,648 through positive 2,147,483,647 hense overflow. You just need bigger type, use `long` or `long long`

Comment: maximum value for int `MAX_INT` if int is 32bit equals to  `2^31 -1 = 2147483647`

Comment: The range of values for a 2's compliment signed 4 byte integer is -2147483648 to 2147483647. As you can see, there is no representation for 2147483648. Either use a larger integer type, which eliminates the immediate problem but still has an upper value limit, or restrict the parameter to a range greater than -2147483648.

Comment: Side note: Look into prime number sieving algorithms like the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) for higher-performance prime number verification. You generate a table with the sieve once at program start up, and then simply check the table for all of the queries in the future.

Comment: Change `if (n<0) n=n*(-1);` to `if (n<0) return false;`.

Answer (score 1):

> *-2147483648 * -1 cannot be represented in type 'int' [signed 32 bit]*

For sure, it cannot, and you know why? A simple fact of representation.

---

Imagine to have 4 bits instead of 32. You would have 1 bit for the sign and 3 for the *absolute value*, right?

Well, lets say you have 0 for positive numbers and 1 for negative numbers in the first bit.

Then you can only represent `2^3`=`8` combinations for the absolute value, right?
Well, you only have 8 positive numbers and 8 negative numbers.

**BUT** 0 is considered as positive, so you have 8 negative, 7 positive and 1 neutral. So you have numbers from `-8` to `7`.

---

In this case you have numbers from `-2147483648` to `2147483647`.

Comment: Calling the non-sign-bits of an integer the mantissa is pretty weird, IDK what to call them but at least not that

Comment: Yes @harold I knew it wasn't the correct term, it's used for IEEE754 if I remember well... I'll edit to call it "absolute value", then it should be an acceptable answer I think, right?

Comment: Perhaps, but that term suggests that `x & 0x7FFFFFFF` computes the absolute value of `x` and it doesn't

Comment: Well, I said it many times, but perhaps that matematicians back in 50s should have simply wasted that damn bit for the negative 0 

Answer (score 0):

If your prime factors are limited to be 2, 3, or 5, then the easiest way is:

```
if (n < 0) return false;
```

But if your prime factors can also be -1, then just make that as an acceptable valid terminal condition.

```
bool check(int n) {
    for (;;) {
        if (n%2 == 0) {
            n /= 2;
        } else if (n%3 == 0) {
            n /= 3;
        } else if (n%5 == 0) {
            n /= 5;
        } else {
            break;
        }   
    }   

    return (n == 1) || (n == -1);
}
```

Comment: Until recently, when `n` is negative, `n/2` can have either of two values, depending on whether the code (i.e., the hardware) rounds down or toward zero. For example, after `n = -3`, n/2 can be 2 if the code rounds down, and it can be 1 if the code rounds toward zero. This calculation works only if the code rounds toward zero. This allowance was changed recently for C and for C++, but I haven't been paying attention, and I don't remember which way the rounding goes.